# writing junit tests for my classes

Tags: java, junit

I would like to write junit tests for my java classes

The objective is to read contents from a text file and doing some basic operations and calculations.

Comment: [JUnit tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JUnit/article.html)

Comment: What do you know about unit tests?

Comment: I am newbie for writing unit tests in junit, above code is for my two classes and I would like to know how to start implementing/writing the unit tests for them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation on JUnit - Brian Roach has given you a link in the comments.

Decide what your classes are supposed to do. Think about how they could go wrong, and how they should deal with bad input.

For each thing that they should do, and each thing they should not do, write a test method that proves that they behave correctly.

If your test becomes long and complicated, that is often a sign that your original code is not structured well enough. Fix it.

Practise.